# How can I use constant ConnectionId in Signalr?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working in Asp.Net Core Mvc Signalr. My system works like below image but connectionid changes every refresh all in another browser. I want to use constant connection id for all users and store this connection id and user's id in database . How Can I use Constant connection Id.

Here is my js code

```
"use strict";


$(document).ready(() => {
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chathub").build();
    connection.on("connected", connecitonid => $("#connectionId").html(connecitonid));

    connection.start();

    $("button").click(() => {
        let message = $("#txtMessage").val();
        var user = $("#sender").val();
        connection.invoke("ClientSendMessage", $("#client").val(),user, message)
            .catch(error => console.log("Error." + error));
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = "me" + ":" + message;
        document.getElementById("son").appendChild(div);
    });

    connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
        var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
        var encodedMsg = user + ":" + msg;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.textContent = encodedMsg;
        document.getElementById("son").appendChild(div);
        
    });

});
```

Here is my hub class

```
using MentorShip.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MentorShip.Hubs
{
    public class SignalRChat:Hub
    {
        

        public async Task ClientSendMessage(string connectionId,string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",user, message);
        }
        public async override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("connected", Context.ConnectionId);
          
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my html code

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row"><h5>Connection ID : <span id="connectionId"></span></h5></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" id="sender" value="Sender Name"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" placeholder="ReceiverId" id="client"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7"> <input type="text" id="txtMessage"> <button>Send</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7" id="son"> </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Here is how code works
[This connection id every time changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8r3i.png)

Comment: why do you want persistent connection id? that connection id is ***meaningful*** only in the current session to help maintain a client connection so that the server can push data to. It does not have any meaning to be saved/persisted or used in some scope out of the context of the current session.

Comment: @Hopeless you are right, if the OP wants to somehow store the connection, he can map it to an user or to a group.

Comment: well, looks like he's trying to ask another question to attempt to solve one same issue as in this previous question of his https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581679/how-can-i-send-the-messages-to-specific-user-using-users-id-which-stored-in-mss So what I commented there is still valuable for your solution.

Comment: You right almost same question but I cant implement with IUserIdProvider and I am trying different solution

Comment: why can't you? it's obviously a good solution and should work. It's in a design from Microsoft asp.net team. All possible scenarios are taken care of.

Comment: @Hopeless How can I fill the GetUserId method. I want to use the id of the users stored in the database. How can I fill the GetUserId method like this.

Comment: @Cankan where do you want to call that? if you mean in the implementation class for `IUserIdProvider`, then it's simple that you can inject everything into the class constructor (like a service class). Suppose you have some service exposing `GetUserId`, you can inject it into the implementation class of `IUserIdProvider` and consume it easily.

Comment: @Hopeless above there is a image how codes world. Then there is a  unique connection id there but I dont want to use that unique connection id I want to use specific constant email adress or User id which stored in db ,  How can i edit Useridprovider class and GetUserId method according to my purpose.